# Display description in Username and Password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a similar login as in https://login.microsoftonline.com/. I want to display a description "someone@example.com" and "Password" in the fields.

I've tried to use the txReplaceFormPassword.js (http://snipplr.com/view/29555/) script to dynamically replace the fields but it is returning html text instead of the actual field.

```
<head>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/txReplaceFormPassword.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.pwdfield').txReplaceFormPassword({
    show_text: 'Password'
});
});
</script>
</head>

<div class="pwdfield">
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new {@class = "k-textbox", style = "width:300px"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
</div>
```

I'm getting the following output in the browser:

[image: PasswordField]

Please let me know how can I get a description inside Password/Username field similar to the two links above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="someone@example.com" /><br />
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

As far as I know, you don't need to use js or jQuery for that. Just set the `placeholder=""` to the text you want to show in the fields.

Take a look on [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp).

**EDIT**

Then use the following jQuery (tested on ie 7):

```
(function($){
var placeholderIsSupported = ('placeholder' in document.createElement('input'));
$.fn.emulatePlaceholder = function(){
    if(!placeholderIsSupported){
        this.each(function(index, element){
            var handle = $(element);
            var placeholder = handle.attr('placeholder');           
            if(handle.val() == ''){
                handle.val(placeholder);    
            }
            handle.blur(function(e){
                var handle = $(this);
                if(handle.val() == ''){
                    handle.val(placeholder);
                }
            });
            handle.focus(function(e){
                var handle = $(this);
                if(handle.val() == placeholder){
                    handle.val('');
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

**USAGE:**

```
$('input').emulatePlaceholder();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFk3G/) example

Comment: Should be the solution except that placeholder is not supported in IE<10

Comment: So I add a jQuery to verify if the `placeholder` property is or isn't supported by the user browser. If it is, ok, nothing changes. But if it isn't the js will simulate it.